# grails sending email: mailService is null always

Tags: email, grails, groovy, grails-plugin

Before posting here, I did browse all thread here and there, 
but not getting it to work, 
Why my mailService is null all the time

Added this is my Config.grooy

```
grails {
   mail {
     host = "smtp.gmail.com"
     port = 465
     username = "xxxx@gmail.com"
     password = "yyyy"
     props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",                     
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"true"]
   }
}
```

and this is my class which will send demo mail

```
class EmailHelper {
    def mailService;

    def sendMailTO() {
        println "mail service:"+mailService
         mailService.sendMail {
            to 'xxxx@gmail.com'
            from 'xxxx@gmail.com'
            subject "Test"
            body "Test";
         }
    }
}
```

And this is how I call from my controller

```
EmailHelper emailHelper = new EmailHelper();
emailHelper.sendMailTO();
```

Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do *not* have to create a bean just for this - that's overkill. Since you're calling the helper from a controller which can use dependency injection, inject it there and pass it to the helper:

```
class MyController {

   def mailService

   def someAction() {
       EmailHelper emailHelper = new EmailHelper()
       emailHelper.mailService = mailService
       emailHelper.sendMailTO()
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Makes more sense here. I agree, I would go with a generic helper (which does more than sending mails) as a bean instead of email helper, which has only one behavior to execute, as a bean.

Answer (score 1):

`MailService` needs to be injected into your `EmailHelper` class via dependency injection. The way you have declared, `mailService` will only work in Grails artifacts like Services and Controllers. This means it will not work if your `EmailHelper` class is in src/groovy. Instead, create your class as a Service like `EmailHelperService` (`grails create-service EmailHelper`) and do dependency injection there.

Comment: Not really understanding the downvote. This answer should briefly explain why his/her approach is not working and a quick way to make it work.

Comment: I think it was because of not thinking about a simpler approach. Same happened to me. :) I rectified it after Burt's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a helper class hopefully under `src/groovy` you have to inject the dependency of `mailService` and then inject the helper to controller instead of instantiating it.

**UPDATE**
I would go with the below approach for a generic helper which does more than just sending mails.

```
//resources.groovy
import mypackage.MyHelper

beans={
    myHelper(MyHelper){
        mailService = ref('mailService')
    }
}

//Controller
Class MyController{
    def myHelper

    def myAction(){...}
}
```